# How to map the query String result to a custom object(model) in sqlalchemy and django?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I want to return result in to custom model(class) but I got this error message:

> SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected

I don't know where I went wrong.

```
 connect = Connector()
 Session = sessionmaker(bind=connect.ConnectorMySql())
 ses = Session()
 query = u"""
      SELECT
           `reports`.ID As 'ID',
            reports.Title AS 'ReportTitle',
           `reports`.Text as 'ReporText',
           `reports`.Status as 'Status',
           `user`.ID AS 'ReporterID',
           `user`.Name as 'ReporterName' ,
           `user`.Username as 'ReporterUserName',
           `user`.ImageProfile as 'ReporterAvatar',
           `Clinet`.ID AS 'ClinetID',
           `Clinet`.SiteUserName AS 'ClinetUserName',
           `Clinet`.ImageProfile as 'ClinetAvatar'
      FROM reports
      JOIN Clinet  on reports.ClinetID = `Clinet`.ID
      JOIN users user on reports.UserID = `user`.ID
      where
           :pClinetID IS NULL OR reports.ClinetID=:pClinetID
      AND
           :pStatus IS NULL OR reports.Status=:pStatus;
 """
 QueryResult=CustomModel()
 QueryResult=ses.query(CustomModel).from_statement(query).all()   

 return QueryResult
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy **and** Django?

Comment: Yes , SQLAlchemy and Django

Answer (score -1):

To use query strings in SQLAlchemy, you have to craft them with [text function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql).

So you should use
`QueryResult=ses.query(CustomModel).from_statement(text(query)).all()`